# Images will not load when deploying to github pages

Tags: reactjs, image, web, deployment, github-pages

I am using create-react-app to build a simple React app, however, the images will not load when I deployed the project to github pages, but they load just fine when I deploy the app using the command prompt.

I am getting this error for all images:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

404 means that it cant find the image. It's probably that you have to change the filepaths. If you can, use absolute paths for the images. That way you will be sure it will work. Otherwise you have to try if it works by changing the path. For example if your images is in an image folder.

Try

/images/image1.jpg

or

./images/image1.jpg

Comment: at first it was like this: assets/teatemples/eb.jpg, then I changed it to: ../assets/teatemples/eb.jpg and it still does not work on github pages

Comment: try with one dot only . and also /assets/teatemples/eb.jpg

Comment: I have tried both solutions, neither seem to be working. Again, if I deploy from cmd it is working perfectly, it just doesn't load the images when I deploy on github pages.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this post is old, maybe will help other web developers or beginners.
A quick fix for this problem on gh-pages is to add:
`${procces.env.PUBLIC_URL}`
in the path of your Route, Link or img tag, before your link.
Example:
For homepage in Route path: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`
For homepage in Link to: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/home`
`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/img/image.png`
I learned this in Web Development Course.

Comment: yup, it works only in the development, but if you deploy your project in github also the images won't be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The problem is with the file path. When you deploy a project on github it is not on a http://localhost:3000 but the URL is http://YOUR_PROFILE.github.io
When deploying the create-react-app to GitHub Pages in package.json add

```
"homepage":"http://YOUR_PROFILE.github.io/MY_APP/"
```

MY_APP change to your repository name. Remember to structure files to have images folder in public directory not in the src. The path to images instead of './images/photo1.jpg' or '/images/photo1.jpg'

> change the path to:  **'./MY_APP/images/photo1.jpg'**

It works like a charm in my case.